# SELECT in CONCAT

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I need to concatenate two columns and I use concat as I see that this function can help me.

An example for concat function is:

```
SELECT CONCAT(column1,'SEPARATOR',column2) FROM table
```

And my query is like this:

```
SELECT
    parent_id AS keep_in_mind_parent_id,
    (SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = keep_in_mind_parent_id)
FROM
    table
WHERE
    id = 3
```

How should I concatenate those columns ? I try it with CONCAT, but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: The `table` you are using in your query, are they the same table or different ones?

Comment: Is the same table, but whatever query I use, the 2 columns must be as two_columns_in_one_string

Comment: What are the column types and what are you getting and what do you want

Comment: I want to get the parent_id and parent_name. The parent id I get using (select parent_id from table where id = 3), but the name of parent id is in another row. parent_id is in the same row with id, but parent_name is not...

Comment: Can u show (cut and paste dont type it) the create table statement. Then supply some sample data. 2 things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the `table` is a tree modeled with parent links (or an "adjacency" model), something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(31) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (parent_id, name)
);
```

If you want to find the row of a given table that is the parent of another row in the same table, you can `INNER JOIN` a table to itself on the parent link. Then you can distinguish values in the parent and child tables by the aliases you give in the `JOIN`. To concatenate the names of the parent and child rows for the child whose `id` is 3, the join would look like this:

```
SELECT child.parent_id, child.id AS id,
       CONCAT(parent.name, ':', child.name) AS path,
       CONCAT(parent.name, ' (#', parent.id, ')') AS parent_name_id
FROM `table` AS child
INNER JOIN `table` AS parent ON child.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE child.id = 3
```

Then tweak the `CONCAT` statements to suit the exact format of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want `group_concat()`.  Without sample data and desired results, it is hard to tell, but one likely possibility is:

```
SELECT parent_id AS keep_in_mind_parent_id,
       (SELECT group_concat(name) FROM table WHERE id = keep_in_mind_parent_id)
FROM table
WHERE id = 3;
```